# How to integrate this region?

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the volume of a region between the graph of the function $f(x,y)=e^{(x^2 + y^2)}$ and  the region $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤ 2\}$. I already expressed $W$ in cylindrical coordinates as it follows:
$W = \{ (r, θ, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : \sqrt1≤ r ≤ \sqrt2; 0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π; 0 ≤ z ≤ e^{(r^2)}\}$

Now I have to triple integrate to find W, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Why are you going from $\mathbb R^{2}$ to $\mathbb R^{3}$? Just use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: 'Complex integration' has  a different meaning altogether. It is not the same as 'Complicated integration'

Comment: Because in the header problem says W is a tridimensional region

Comment: Sorry... im new at this